# Xibs and Scrollview

Tags: ios

I'm still pretty new at this, so bear with me. I thought I would be able to load a Xib in a ScrollView, as  I have seen apps that seem to do this, but we're are talking two different classes. But I'll ask anyway - Is there any practical way to have a scrollView with a static Xib over the top, where buttons defined in the UI don't move while a view underneath does. I'm sure it's easily doable in cocos2d, but for what I want to do, it's a bit overkill.

--- Edit ---

At the risk of embarrassing myself, I tried both possible solutions. Adding a button grammatically adds a button that moves when I scroll. Adding the nib seems to keep the scroll screen from scrolling. Here's the code, without trying to add any buttons everything works fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"View Loaded");


    [mdm setMapSetupInfoWithRows:60 columns:90 cellSize:32];
    [mdm initMapDataWithOriginsUsingCenter:TRUE];

    NSLog(@"MapViewContoller.mapArrayCount = %d",[[mdm mapArray]count]);

    // create the MapView with the screen size create by MapDataManager
     mapView = [[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:[mdm mapRect]];

    // Create the UIScrollView to have the size of the window, matching the window (screen) size
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[mdm windowRect]];
    [scrollView setBounds:[mdm windowRect]];

    // Tell the scrollview how big it is and set other options
    [scrollView setContentSize:[mdm mapRect].size];
    [scrollView setBounces:NO];
    [scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:.5];
    [scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:10];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];


    //add the MapView as a subview of the scrollView
    [scrollView addSubview:mapView];

    //add the scrollView to the current one....
    [[self view] addSubview:scrollView];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MapViewController" owner:self options:nil];


    [self generNewMap];
}
```

Anything else I'm trying to do wrong? after looking at this more it does seem doable.

Answer (score 0):

You should set things with a hierarchy like this.

UIViewController

- UIScrollView
- Static Buttons etc

Then in interface builder, or code, just add the static buttons etc to the self.view.

I do everything in code so it would look something like

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //add scrollview
    appScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    appScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [appScroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    appScroll.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    appScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1600, 480);
    [appScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    appScroll.bounces = NO;
    appScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    appScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    appScroll.clipsToBounds = YES;
    appScroll.delaysContentTouches = YES;
    appScroll.center = (CGPoint){ 160, 240 };
    [appScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:appScroll];


    //back
    backBut = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]];
    backBut.center = (CGPoint){ 40, 430 };
    backBut.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.3,0.3);
    [backBut setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
    [self.view addSubview: backBut];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to specify the owner when loading the XIB. For example:

- Define an IBOutlet on your UIViewController

  @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView* myScrollViewContent
- Create a XIB, specify the owner as your UIViewController class
- Wire the components defined in the XIB to the outlets defined in the UIViewController class

Then in code do this:

```
//Because the owner is 'self' the bundle loader will inject any properties defined . . 
//. . . . and wired in the XIB to the owner's outlets
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXibName" owner:self options:nil];
//Now do something with self.myScrollViewContent - ie add it to the scroll view.
```

**Custom Scroll-view sub-class**

If you wanted should be able to use the same approach by creating a cusom scroll-view subclass and specifying an outlet there. . . The UIView would be loaded directly onto the sub-class, then. . . (you'd still have to add it as sub-view).

For more complex requirements, I personally like to build my views with pure code, but it is possible to arrange things neatly with XIBs.